# Converting a string of mac address into hex in C

Tags: c, embedded, hex, esp32

I want to convert a string of mac address into hex format.

- Input:

```
char remote_device_mac[] = "00a05056a810";
```

- Expected output:

```
uint8_t base_mac_addr[6] = {0x00,0xa0,0x50,0x56,0xa8,0x10};
```

My code:-

```
char dummy[2] = {0};
int j = 0;
uint8_t num = 0;
     for(int k=0;k<6;k++)
     {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            dummy[i] = remote_device_mac[i+j];

        num = (int)strtol(dummy, NULL, 8);
        j=j+2;
        sprintf(base_mac_addr[k], "%x", num);

        num = 0; 
        memset(dummy,0,2);
     }
```

Comment: You forgot about the NUL string terminator. `dummy[2]` -> `dummy[3]` (you need space for the NUL terminator).

Comment: Also think about the 8 in the parameters of `strtol`. Hint: 8 is wrong.

Comment: And what is the `sprintf` supposed to do here ??? Did you get compiler warnings? Consider them as errors.

Comment: I changed `dummy[2]` to [3] and in `strtol` I changed 8 to 16. Not getting any warning in compiler for using `sprintf` but my code crashes at this point. How can I change this. It is a embedded code to connect a ble server by its mac address using MCU.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with sprintf? Instead of `sprintf` you want something like: `base_mac_add[k] = num)`, don't you? Reads the documentation of  `sprintf` carefully.

Comment: Hexadecimal is not a data type, it is a _presentation_.  Your "expected output" is an array of 8 bit integers.  You converted from a string to an integer and then bizarrely back to a string again.

Answer (score 1):

```
char dummy[2] = {0};
```

size of `dummy` has at least 3 bytes (2 for value in hexa, 1 for `\0`). So you can declare as:

```
char dummy[3] = "00";
```

Use base = 16 instead of 10, because you want to convert to hexadecimal.

```
num = strtol(dummy, &ptr, 16);
```

`sprintf` is not necessary (use it if you want to copy number into a string).

```
// assign each base_mac_addr to num.
base_mac_addr[k] = num;
```

Finally, the code as below:

```
     for(int k=0;k<6;k++)
     {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            dummy[i] = remote_device_mac[i+j];
        num = strtol(dummy, &ptr, 16);
        j=j+2;
        printf("0x%2x\n", num);
        base_mac_addr[k] = num;
     }
```